# RobotFramework: Converting date to get Month name

Tags: robotframework, date-format

Any site around date format days that the conversion needs **MMM** but this wont work. When i do...

```
${date_to_search_for}=  Convert Date  2017-06-14 13:03:02.506610  date_format=%Y-%M-%d %H:%m:%S.%f  result_format=%d %MMM %Y 00:00:00  exclude_millis=True
```

I get

```
14 06MM 2017 00:00:00
```

Obviously am looking for Jun in this example

Answer (score 2):

`%MMM` is not a valid directive in `datetime`. You want to use `%b` if you want a month's abbreviated name. Your `result_format` should be:

```
result_format=%d %b %Y 00:00:00
```